# Render links in Datatables issue

Tags: jquery, datatables

I can't seem to figure out what my issue is with rendering this link through the Datatables Jquery.

my data set comes out like this

```
*/ Code to get data /* .......
pre.push(category, bdate, title, host, loc, 'Details' , sumcomms, auth, edate, ID, body, created, modified);
                    dataSet[i] = pre;
*/ End code to get data /* .......
```

I know this is correct because i can actually create the table, and see it. However, the render part in the next bit of code is returning a blank cell...

```
$('#FTable').DataTable({
                    data: dataSet,
                    bProcessing: true,
                    iDisplayLength: 25,
                    columnDefs: [

                        /******* ISSUE HERE *******/
                        {
                            targets: [5],
                            render: function(data, type, row, meta) {
                                data = '<button class="btn" onlick="create_dModal(' + row[9] + row[0], row[10], row[1], row[3], row[4], row[7], row[2], row[12] + ')"> Display </button>';
                                return data;
                            }
                        },

                        {
                            targets: [9],
                            visible: false,
                            searchable: false
                        },
                        {
                            targets: [10],
                            visible: false,
                            searchable: false
                        },
                        {
                            targets: [11],
                            visible: false,
                            searchable: false
                        },

                    ],

                    columns: [{
                            title: "Category"
                        },
                        {
                            title: "Date"
                        },
                        {
                            title: "Title"
                        },
                        {
                            title: "Host"
                        },
                        {
                            title: "Location"
                        },
                        {
                            title: "Details",

                            type: "display",

                        },
                        {
                            title: "Comments"
                        },
                        {
                            title: "Posted By"
                        },
                        {
                            title: "End Date"
                        },
                        {
                            title: "ID"
                        },
                        {
                            title: "Details (full)"
                        },
                        {
                            title: "Created Date"
                        },
                        {
                            title: "Last Modified"
                        }

                    ],

                });
```

Comment: Not sure but if could be the use of columnDefs and columns. Try putting what's in the columnDefs in the columns initializer

Comment: instead of trying to redefine data try  return  '<button class="btn" onlick="create_dModal(' + row[9] + row[0], row[10], row[1], row[3], row[4], row[7], row[2], row[12] + ')"> Display </button>';

Comment: @bindrid I tested this it didn't seem to work

Comment: Is it not rendering at all?  BTW, that is a submit button by default. You might need to add type='button' to it.

Comment: another observation, of any of those values are strings, you are going to get an error when the user clicks on the button

Comment: I see the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having said all of that, this is what I would actually do (since datatables requires jQuery, this solution is mostly in jquery).

shown here: http://live.datatables.net/gavivefo/1/edit

```
$(document).ready( function () {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    columnDefs:[{targets:[-1], render:function(data,type,row, meta){
      return '<button type="button">Display</button>';
  }}]
 });

  $('#example').on("click", "button", function(){
       var row = $(this).closest("tr");
       var rowData = $("#example").DataTable().rows(row).data()[0];
       create_dModal(rowData);


  })
} );

function create_dModal(data){

   alert("Name:" + data[0] + "\nPosition:" + data[1] + "\nOffice:" + data[2]);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot tell which values are numbers and what are strings so for the sake of argument, lets pretend that 0, 9 and 4 are strings and everything else are numbers. Then your render would look like...

```
 var r = '<button type="button" onclick="create_dModal(';
 // assuming 9 and 0 are strings
 // your commas in quotes cause you are making a string
 r += '"' + row[9] + row[0] + "', "; 
 // now the rest of the values as numbers
 // ( you could do this all on one like but I did the += stuff for clarity)
 r += row[10] + ', ';
 r += row[1] + ', ';
 r += row[3] + ', ';
 r += row[4] + ', ';
 r += row[7] + ', ';
 r += row[2] + ', '; 
 r += row[12];
 r += ')">Display</button>';

 return r;
```

where your functions looks something like

```
 function create_dModal(str_9_0, num_10, num_1, num_3, num_4, num_7, num_2, num_12)
```